# phonegap plugins don't work on android

Tags: android, cordova

after i installed the cordova-plugin-statusbar plugin, it worked perfectly on my phone. however, when i tried to install a plugin called "wifiwizard" it didn't work at all. same as any other none-official plugin.
after so many attempts, i figured out that cordova didn't execute "prepare android", it only executes "prepare browser", here is a screenshot:
[image: i think cordova should prepare android too]

[image: the status bar plugin works perfectly, but the wifiwizard doesn't.]

Comment: what is the plugin "hotspot"? Also, please add the output of "cordova plugin" command.

Comment: C:\Users\kaddy\Documents\masterave\WiPassMe\WiPassMe>cordova plugin
com.pylonproducts.wifiwizard 0.2.11 "WifiWizard"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.1 "Whitelist"

Comment: Are you testing on the phonegap developer app? you can't run 3rd party plugins on the developer app, only the plugins that were included in the app when phonegap team compiled it. You have to run your app or add the plugins to the developer app and compile it.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the plugin you are using, https://github.com/parsonsmatt/WifiWizard

Then it looks like you have the API wrong. The correct use of the plugin would be the following.

```
cordova.plugins.WifiWizard.isWifiEnabled(l_success, l_fail);
```

UPDATE:

It looks like you are using on document ready,  not on device ready.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(e) {
  ...  Your code here
} , false);
```

Plugin usually aren't available until the device is ready.